# How do I fix these margins? Only working ok in Firefox

Tags: css, position, css-float

I'm having issues with the margins in browsers (other than Firefox) on this page:

http://jumpthru.net/newsite/commentary/

Here is the CSS:

```
#container3 {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 -240px;
    width: 100%;
}

#content3 {
    margin: 0 210px 0 -45px;
    width:500px;
}

#primary, #secondary {
    left:920px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 40px;
    position:absolute;
    width: 220px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of a strange way to build up the page..
I recommend you to create a 2 column layout in main2..
Left for menu and right for the comments header, with beneath that the content and the recent comments div..

And, start using clearfix: http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue in Chrome by changing this CSS:

```
#primary, #secondary {
left: 980px; /*was 920px*/
overflow: hidden;
padding-top: 40px;
position: absolute;
width: 220px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thank you for your update, but the issue seems to be that the left alignment is not consistent in Firefox vs Chrome, so the 940 looks good in Firefox, and 980 in chrome.  But is there a way to do both?  I'm seeing that I can't write conditional statements for Chrome without using some javascript.  Thank you for your help

Comment: if chrome renders the page without a scroll bar that could be moving the page over 20 pixels. see my answer below for why this causes things to move.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using absolute position on #primary, this is based on the window so when i resize the window the "Recent Comments" section moves. So depending on the resolution of the users screen and the size of their browser this will move.

add position relative to the main2 div. Then change the left value on the #primary to right with a value of 0. this will keep it on the right side and always in the same place.

```
#main2 {
  position: relative;
  ...
}

#primary, #secondary {
    right: 0;
    ...
}
```

EDIT: The reason this works is when you use position: absolute the value is absolute the nearest relative parent element. if the element as no parent elements with position: relative it will be absolute to the browser window. Hope that makes sense.